# what does "ramp" mean in lsof name

Tags: tibco, lsof

I am using lsof to check connections to a remote Tibco server(7000).  I am using this command..

line

```
lsof -p 4567 | grep TCP | grep 7000

java    4446  app  319u  IPv6            9150778       0t0     TCP localhost:49756->test-tibco-test.com:ramp (ESTABLISHED)
java    4446  app  325u  IPv6            9150793       0t0     TCP localhost:49756->test-tibco-test.com:54561->dfw-qa.prod.testqa.com:7000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What does the "ramp" mean in the first output?

Answer (score 1):

lsof translates "well-known" port numbers to human readable string (e.g., 25 -> smtp, 80 -> http etc.).  Per http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml, "ramp" should mean port 7227 (the "Registry A & M Protocol").

Note that this only means that port 7227 is being used, not that you actually have the "Registry A & M Protocol" (whatever that is) running on that port.  Most likely, somebody configured a TIBCO EMS server to use port 7227 (its default port is 7222 and many people start counting upwards from there if they need multiple servers with different ports running on the same machine).

You can add the option `-P` (capital letter P) to your lsof command to avoid this translation of port numbers into human readable names.